# How do I find the average of only a partial range using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find the average (excluding min and max values) of a range of date in Google Sheets. The problem is that the range will continue to grow.

I have the formula to drop min and max from the range1, but I need help figuring out how to calculate this formula based on only the last X entries in range1.

Drop min & max:

```
=(SUM(A1:Z1)-MAX(A1:Z1)-MIN(A1:Z1))/(COUNT(A1:Z1)-2)
```

In this [sample doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17BbqyUxaRHOWBL_AKAgItSvPVKHXXARxrUATP2cbnFw/edit?usp=sharing) I need to calculate the average of only the last 8 entries (while dropping the high and low values), to determine a rolling 6 month average. New entries will be input each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)))) - MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)))) - MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2))))) / (COUNT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2))))-2)
```

OR

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2))),"<>"&MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2))),"<>" & MIN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)-5) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,MATCH(1E+99,2:2)))))
```

You can replace the `- 5` in four places with a cell value, for example if you want more or less than the last 6 months, you could put the number of months desired in a cell say A3.  Then replace the `5` with `A3-1`.

The basic building block is the `MATCH(1E+99,2:2)` which will find the last cell in row 2 with a number. So using that I used the ADDRESS() function to return the beginning and ending cell addresses with INDIRECT().

Comment: Thanks Scott!  I took your advice and replaced the -5 with a cell value, and it worked beautifully.

Comment: @JoshSwenson Glad to help, Please consider marking as correct by clicking on the green check ark by the answer.